# Нахождение зависимости между двумя наборами данных

Tags: математика, статистика

Имеется два набора данных, конкретно векторы a1(x11,y11)...an(x1n,y1n) и зависимые векторы b1(x21,y21)...bn(x2n,y2n). Имеется возможность экспериментально измерить векторы b для какого либо количества a, затем необходимо вывести какую то зависимость b от a. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Вообще-то от сути происходящего, грубо говоря - от физики. Смотреть модель, что происходит. Нет - тогда копаться от простых линейных зависимостей и далее усложнять. Примерно (очень примерно) так. Как мне кажется... :)

Comment: Вы поставили задачу : `x ?F y == ?R` из двух переменных. Что есть данные, x и y . Нужно найти зависимость ?F, такая чтобы удовлетворяло условию ?R. Уравнение из двух переменных имеет огромный массив решений. Сначала уточните свои запросы для решения ?R. Будет у вас цель, будет решение.

Comment: Можно ещё покопать в сторонц выборочной корреляции (держа, конечно, в уме, что ниличие корреляции ещё не означает наличие причинно-следственной связи). Но такой метод вам лишь скажет, есть ли зависимость, саму зависимость он не может найти.